# Consultar tabela pela chave estrangeira no C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Então, tenho um projeto de Pizzaria e tenho algumas tabelas, tais como: Cadastro de Cliente, Cadastro de Funcionário, Cadastro de Pedido e etc.
Já criei uma tabela do Cliente e Funcionários e está tudo OK.
Na tabela de Cadastro de Pedido há dois campos que pede o ID do Funcionário e o ID do Cliente. 
Tem como selecionar o Funcionário e o Cliente apenas pesquisando o nome de ambos?
Segue o link para entender melhor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPvpU.png
As chaves estrangeiras do Pedido são: id_funcionar e id_cliente.

Comment: Usa o comando join na consulta.

Comment: Poste seu codigo e o que vc ja fez, assim e melhor para ajudar vc.

Comment: Você está usando Entity Framework?

Comment: @Anderson Trindade, a minha resposta solucionou a sua dúvida ? Posso ajudar em mais alguma coisa ?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia juntar a tabela Funcionário com Cliente e Pedido.

Ex:

```
 SELECT CLIENTE.NOME, CLIENTE.ID, FUNCIONARIO.NOME, FUNCIONARIO.ID, PEDIDO.ID
 FROM PEDIDO
 INNER JOIN CLIENTE
 ON CLIENTE.ID = PEDIDO.ID_CLIENTE
 INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO.ID 
 ON  ON FUNCIONARIO.ID = PEDIDO.ID_FUNCIONARIO
 WHERE CLIENTE.NOME = 'LUÃ GOVINDA MENDES SOUZA'
```

Porem, não aconselho você fazer isso pois CLIENTE.NOME e FUNCIONARIO.NOME não são chaves da tabela, tendo a possibilidade de você receber mais de um registro na query acima.